# MVC 3 ViewModel Pattern issue (using RAZOR)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I've researched this issue and can not find a solution. My problem is that in my view, I can not view the properties of my ViewModel (e.g., Model.Supplier.SupplerName). Intellisense will only allow me to go Model.Suppliers, or Model.ToolTypes, or Model.ToolTypesSuppliers . I can not get the properties of each of these models that I included into the ViewModel.

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ToolOrder.Models
{
    public class ToolTypeSupplierViewModel
    {
        public ToolTypeSupplierViewModel(IEnumerable<ToolType> tooltypes, IEnumerable<Supplier> suppliers, IEnumerable<ToolTypeSupplier> tooltypesuppliers)
        {
            this.ToolTypes = tooltypes;
            this.Suppliers = suppliers;
            this.ToolTypeSuppliers = tooltypesuppliers;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ToolType> ToolTypes { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<ToolTypeSupplier> ToolTypeSuppliers { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ListToolTypeSupplierOptions()
{
    var _tooltypelist =_repository.FetchAllToolTypeOptions();
    var _supplierlist = _repository.FetchAllSupplierOptions();
    var _toolstypesupplierlist = _repository.FetchAllToolTypeSupplierOptions();

    return View(new ToolTypeSupplierViewModel(_tooltypelist, _supplierlist, _toolstypesupplierlist));
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ToolOrder.Models.ToolTypeSupplierViewModel>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Tool TYpe</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Last Modified </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.) {
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated or if any further clarification is required, I can follow up. I apologize if this is somewhat vague, I've been up trying to figure out why I can not pull the the properties of each Model that I've included in my ViewModel. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to see the Intellisense properties in the `foreach` statement off of the `Model` or inside the loop off of the `item`? In the statement of the `foreach` you are only going to get Intellisense for collection types. Then inside the loop if you did `item.` then you should see the properties for which ever collection type you chose.

Comment: @munozca a total other topic but a tip: I would use a Facade Layer which is calling your 3 repository methods. Then your facade layer would return a data transfer object to the rich client :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somehow misleading, so i'll try to answer both cases.

1. As i see you pass single instance of `ToolTypeSupplierViewModel` to your view from controller, and not enumerable. If this is not mistake, than mistake is in your view - model should be not IEnumerable of  `ToolTypeSupplierViewModel`, but single `ToolTypeSupplierViewModel`. In this case, you could iterate over Model.ToolTypes, Suppliers, etc. Directly
2. If the mistake is not in view, but in controller and model should be of type `IEnumerable<ToolTypeSupplierViewModel>`, than first you sould iterate over Model directly, as it IS Enumerable itself. Its items are `ToolTypeSupplierViewModel`. In this case, code will be as ysrb suggested

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  @foreach (var supplier in item.Suppliers){
    <tr>
        <td>
           @supplier.SupplierName
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

It seems you need to loop through the Suppliers it's IEnumerable.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! It is strange that in this article [LINK](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx) Stephen Walker was able to chain down the ViewModel in his view. Any reason why I wasn't able to?

Comment: @munozca In the last example, he is just using Single object as the ViewModel (ProductViewModel) while you are using IEnumerable<ToolOrder.Models.ToolTypeSupplierViewModel> object. You can do the same if you use ToolOrder.Models.ToolTypeSupplierViewModel Model.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@using ToolOrder.Models` at the top of your Razor file.

or in web.config, find the namespaces section and add it there

```
  <namespaces>
    ...
    <add namespace="ToolOrder.Models" />
```